# Free Throw Probability

Tags: probability

I was asked this in an interview today. Would you rather try to make 2/3 free throws or 4/6? Why?

I reasoned that if my chance of making an individual shot was > 2/3, I would go for 4/6 because it provided me a better chance at approaching the long run distribution.

Comment: Does it have to be exactly 2 out of 3 and 4 out of 6 or are you saying at least 2 out of 3 and at least 4 out of 6?

Comment: Exactly, and each shot is independent of the others.

Comment: For the reasons you suggested, I'd say prefer 2/3 if you're a bad shooter (your average is less than 2/3) and 4/6 if you're a good shooter (your average is more than 2/3).

Comment: Yes, for p<0.78, go for the 2 out of 3. For more, the 4/6 is better. It makes intuitive sense as well: Many improbable events all happening is highly improbable. So if your chance is great, go for 4/6 because the improbable events that you miss each time are 4. If your chance is small, go for 2/3 because the improbable events that you hit are just 2.

Comment: Please amend your question to reflect your clarification in comments.

Comment: +1 to @CloseToC: $0.78 = \left(2+\sqrt{34}\right)/10$ is the point at which the two probabilities of $3 p^2 - 2 p^3$ and $10 p^6-24 p^5+15 p^4$ cross over.

Comment: Everyone else seems to have understood the context - but throwing/shooting what/whom?

Comment: @Scortchi Presumably basketball, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_throw.  Similar in concept to penalty kicks in soccer.

Comment: @user1357015 hitting exactly is the same as at least since you can miss the rest intentionally after hitting your target.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question with the "exactly 4 of 6" vs "exactly 2 of 3" isn't very interesting, because P("hit exactly 2 of 3 throws") is *always* better, (unless p=0 or 1 - when the chance is 0, in which case they're equal at 0).

The ratio of probabilities P(4 of 6)/P(2 of 3) is

$$\frac{{{6}\choose {4}} p^4 (1-p)^2}{{3\choose 2} p^2 (1-p)} = 5 p^2(1-p)\,.$$

This is maximized at $p=2/3$, where the ratio reaches 20/27 (32.9% chance for 4 of 6, 44.4% chance for 2 of 3).

---

The question "at least 4 of 6" vs "at least 2 of 3" is a bit more interesting.

There, "at least 4 of 6" wins if p>0.7831 (roughly)

[image]

[As whuber points out in comments, this point may be solved for algebraically; it's exactly $\frac{2+\sqrt{34}}{10}$.]

Comment: You're right; there is some ambiguity.  However (despite a clarifying comment by the OP!) I believe most people (including mathematicians) would interpret 3/3 as being included in the event "making 2/3" and 5/6 or 6/6 as "making 4/6". Consider, too, that if a reward attaches to making an *exact* number, then a rational strategy would be to miss all throws taken after that number was reached--in which case the chance of "exactly" ought to be computed as the chance of "equal to or more than" anyway.

Comment: @whuber Ah, thanks, a mistake in my code. It's the point where `pbinom(4,6,p)-pbinom(2,3,p)` crosses 0... but what I need is `pbinom(3,6,p)-pbinom(1,3,p)`. [I seem to be making more mistakes in details than usual the last few days.] I will fix.

Comment: +1 By examining the difference between the probabilities you obtain the equation $0=(15 p^4 - 24 p^5 + 10 p^6)-(3 p^2 - 2 p^3)=(p-1)^2 p^2 (10 p^2-4p-3)$ for the crossover point. Both $0$ and $1$ are double roots, as one would expect from the plots--making this polynomial easy to factor--and the remaining positive root is found with the quadratic formula as $\left(2+\sqrt{34}\right)/10\approx 0.783095$. (Equating the ratio to unity leads to the same quadratic equation.)